# Django Post or None

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query with multiple filters or none

```
technician = request.POST.get('technician')
## in the previous screen the user may not have informed the parameter, it should not be required

uniorg = request.POST.get('uniorg')
## in the previous screen the user may not have informed the parameter, it should not be required

calls = Call.objects.filter(
    technician=technician,
    uniorg=uniorg,
    ...)
```

I tried:

```
technician = request.POST.get('technician', '')
```

and

```
technician = request.POST.get('technician' or None)
```

Not all parameters are required.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use dictionary parameter expansion:

```
filters = {k: v for k, v in request.POST.items() if k in ['technician', 'uniorg', ...]}
calls = Call.objects.filter(**filters)
```

or, if you're sure that only actual valid filter values can be in the POST, pass it directly:

```
calls = Call.objects.filter(**request.POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Final code

```
list_filters = ['type', 'technician', 'ended', 'uniorg']
filters = {k: v for k, v in request.POST.items() if k in list_filters}

    for l in list_filters:
        if request.POST[l] == '0' or request.POST[l] == '':
            del filters[l]
    calls = Call.objects.filter(start_time__gte=start_date, start_time__lte=end_date, **filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
qs = Call.objects.all()

technician = request.POST.get('technician')
if technician is not None:
    qs = qs.filter(technician=technician)

uniorg = request.POST.get('uniorg')
if uniorg is not None:
    qs = qs.filter(uniorg=uniorg)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the variables that came from POST, something like:
data = dict (request.POST.lists ())
and put inside a query?

Comment: It is possible (see @DanielRosemans answer). But it probably is a good idea to get each filter value explicitly, because if there is any content in `request.POST` that is NOT a valid field of the model `Call`, then an exception will be raised and your server will return a 500 error.

Comment: Right, i see. 
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)? it's really good tool for providing filter by GET parameters (note that I have no idea about your data base design so this code might not work)

```
# filters.py
class CallFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Call
        fields = ['technician', 'uniorg',]

# view.py
items = CallFilter(request.GET, queryset=Call.objects.all())
```